# can not add a new value in a custom list

Tags: error, custom-list, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, http-400-bad-request

I running:
 - Windows server 2012
 - Sharepoint 2013
 - Visual studio 2013

I created a custom list in visual studio and when i'm trying to add a new value inside I got "unexpected response from server: Error 400 bad request".

I found "The web browser may be too recent, or the HTTP server may be too old" which is the corresponding description for this error. Of course it doesn't help me.

Why am I having this message. Could someone help me?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to add a new value to the list? If you are using the REST API, it may be the result of a malformed request URL.

Comment: I'm using a REST API.

Answer (score 0):

The issue were comming from the Sharepoint Timer Job (Windows/services/Sharepoint Timer)
which was in an infinite loop, blocking any data writing on the server.
I restarted it and it worked.